# CriteriaQuery order by FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I am using JPA Specification Queries where we follow the common Architecture as below for the Queries

```
@Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

        // Create a new predicate list
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        // Add criteria to predicates
        for (SearchCriteria criteria : list) {

            switch (criteria.getOperation()) {
            
            case EQUAL:
                predicates.add((Objects.isNull(criteria.getJoinMap()) || criteria.getJoinMap().isEmpty())
                        ? builder.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue())
                        : builder.equal(getOrCreateJoins(root, criteria.getJoinMap()).get(criteria.getKey()),
                                criteria.getValue()));
                break;
            case MATCH:
                predicates.add((Objects.isNull(criteria.getJoinMap()) || criteria.getJoinMap().isEmpty())
                        ? builder.like(builder.lower(root.get(criteria.getKey())),
                                "%" + criteria.getValue().toString().toLowerCase() + "%")
                        : builder.like(
                                builder.lower(getOrCreateJoins(root, criteria.getJoinMap()).get(criteria.getKey())),
                                "%" + criteria.getValue().toString().toLowerCase() + "%"));

                break;
            
            
            case SORT_ASC:
                query.orderBy((Objects.isNull(criteria.getJoinMap()) || criteria.getJoinMap().isEmpty())
                        ? builder.asc(root.get(criteria.getKey()))
                        : builder.asc(getOrCreateJoins(root, criteria.getJoinMap()).get(criteria.getKey())));
                break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                query.orderBy((Objects.isNull(criteria.getJoinMap()) || criteria.getJoinMap().isEmpty())
                        ? builder.desc(root.get(criteria.getKey()))
                        : builder.desc(getOrCreateJoins(root, criteria.getJoinMap()).get(criteria.getKey())));
            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        return isSearchOperationOr ? builder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]))
                : builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
```

In this we have key and value/values which are being processed but I want the order of Ids which I provide in IN Query to be same in order while the results are being fetched.

Already gone through the FIND_IN_SET term as from mysql it is possible but any idea how to configure here in the above code?

Comment: Can you please show how you would do that with JPQL or SQL?

Comment: @simon Martinelli   Probably by below code?

@Query(value = "select i from ItemEntity i where i.secondaryId in :ids 
       order by FIND_IN_SET(i.secondaryId, :idStr)")
List<ItemEntity> itemsIn(@Param("ids") List<UUID> ids, @Param("idStr") String idStr);

Comment: FIND_IN_SET is not JPA

Comment: Hmm then is there any way to do this by JPA Specification?

Comment: I am also in search of this type of query like I want to retain the order of Ids I provide in IN clause and later on not to allow sql to change its order..!! By this similar architecture.